# Getting Multiple npm errors while publishing

Tags: node.js, npm

I am getting multiple npm errors Here while running `npm publish`

[Error Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3ie3.jpg)

My package.json

```json
{
  "name": "@iamjarvis/text-shadow",
  "version": "1.1.3",
  "description": "Applies text shadow",
  "main": "index.js",
  "publishConfig": {
    "access": "public"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/star-warrior/text-shadow-npm.git"
  },
  "author": "Jay Mehta",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/star-warrior/text-shadow-npm/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/star-warrior/text-shadow-npm#readme"
}
```

I tried `npm publish --force` `sudo npm publish` `npm publish (my registry name)` But didnt work ...

How to solve this ?

Comment: test installed `node_modules`  by command  `npm audit`

Comment: yes , I've verified my email address , That's how I logged in , and I am not using any node modules .....